Vercel --prebuilt Issue with FastAPI and Github Actions
I’m trying to deploy a FastAPI app using Github Actions to Vercel. I can successfully deploy it without using the --prebuilt tag. However, it seems to me that the --prebuilt tag prevents the whole source code to be shared/deployed to Vercel according to the docs https://vercel.com/docs/cli/build ? So the issue is that, apparently, Vercel can’t detect .vercel/output/builds.json file/folder even though it looks like vercel build command does create it.
Command
vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
Error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/builds.json'
Project Setup
api
  |-- routes
  |      |-- middleware.py
  |      |-- auth_route.py
  |      |-- ...
  |-- main.py
tests
  |-- unit_tests
  |       |-- test_main.py
  |       |-- test_auth_route.py
  |       |-- ...
requirements.txt
README.md
vercel.json

vercel.json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/main.py"
    }
  ]
}

ci.yml
name: Run Tests and Deploy to Vercel

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.11.5'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Run tests
      run: |
        pytest

    # deploy to vercel
    - name: Install Vercel CLI
      run: npm install --global vercel@latest

    - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
      run: vercel pull --yes --environment=preview --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

    - name: Build Project Artifacts
      run: vercel build --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

    - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
      run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

Full Log
Run vercel build --token=***
  vercel build --token=***
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64/lib
  
Vercel CLI 39.1.2
WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
Installing required dependencies...
Build Completed in .vercel/output [4s]

Run vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=***
  vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=***
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.5/x64/lib
  
Vercel CLI 39.1.2
Retrieving project…
Deploying redhorseacademy-projects/fastapi_demo
Uploading [--------------------] (0.0B/8.4MB)
(node:1865) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventTarget memory leak detected. 11 abort listeners added to [AbortSignal]. Use events.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Uploading [=====---------------] (2.1MB/8.4MB)
Uploading [==========----------] (4.2MB/8.4MB)
Uploading [===============-----] (6.3MB/8.4MB)
Uploading [====================] (8.4MB/8.4MB)
Inspect: https://vercel.com/redhorseacademy-projects/fastapi_demo/6e2Q9vtYnY25YHu7rtBXviBYiQUb [10s]
Preview: https://fastapidemo-juxg522yb-redhorseacademy-projects.vercel.app [10s]
Queued
Building
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/builds.json'
https://fastapidemo-juxg522yb-redhorseacademy-projects.vercel.app
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I tried building/deploying locally using Vercel CLI and it turns out I also run into the same issue despite the file .vercel/output/builds.json being in the local directory.
(fastapi_env) (base) redhorseacademyPC:fastapi_demo redhorseacademy$ vercel build
Vercel CLI 39.1.2
WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
Installing required dependencies...
✅  Build Completed in .vercel/output [9s]
(fastapi_env) (base) redhorseacademyPC:fastapi_demo redhorseacademy$ vercel deploy --prebuilt --archive=tgz
Vercel CLI 39.1.2
  Inspect: https://vercel.com/redhorseacademy-projects/fastapi_demo/D7sF6esFWwpRLEbhCRdibYFNKyCn [6m]
✅  Preview: https://fastapidemo-38s604pe3-redhorseacademy-projects.vercel.app [6m]
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/builds.json'

.vercel/output/builds.json
{
  "//": "This file was generated by the `vercel build` command. It is not part of the Build Output API.",
  "target": "preview",
  "argv": [
    "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "/usr/local/bin/vercel",
    "build"
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "require": "@vercel/python",
      "requirePath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vercel/node_modules/@vercel/python/dist/index.js",
      "apiVersion": 3,
      "src": "app/main.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ]
}

Lastly, I've made the changes suggest https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/12683 here as well as checked this discussion https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/7092 (which is the exact same issue but couldn't quite understand the solution besides removing --prebuilt in the yaml file) but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated :)

Remove the vercel build Step
For Flask apps, there’s no build process like in frontend apps. The vercel build step might not be necessary unless you've explicitly set up a custom build process in vercel.json. Remove the following line from your workflow:
- name: Build Project Artifacts
  run: vercel build --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

Please accept this as solution if it is working for you.
